# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892 error on running npm run dev

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run react next js application with npm run dev but I am getting following error:

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892

I have uninstalled and reinstalled node.js and also npm. I have also deleted node_modules and added them again but nothing helped. Can any one please guide me how to over come this issue!

[image: Error on running npm run dev]

Comment: Does this file `next` exist?

Comment: @DawidPura Yes.next folder does exist in the application.

Comment: Can you share the `package.json` file?

Comment: {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.4",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}

Comment: @DawidPura I get this error each time I run application. to over come I always clone my repo from github and run npm install and application runs fine. But if I close application and run again then the above error came back!

Comment: Do you use `npm install` before running any `npm run`?

Comment: I find another way, forst delete node modules and run npm install and then npm run dev and it works!